# How to make first letter lowercase in span with css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this xml

```
<dg>(<date>B.1987</date>)</dg>
```

and after formatting with CSS I have this html

`<span class="dateGroup"> (<span class="date"> B.1987</span>)</span`>

What I want to do is make the letter "B" lowercase so the first letter of the span having the class date.
I have searched the internet but it seem's to be only possible for tage `<p></p>`

Could you advice please?

Comment: Why don't you just make `.date` lowercase with css? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform

Comment: Are there cases were you have more than one letter?

Comment: There's no way to target characters in CSS, you'd have to use javascript to wrap that character in an element.

Comment: add css style {text-transform: lowercase;} B will become lowercase

Comment: Thank you for the answer but in case there is so many caracters all the string will be in lowercase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also can use the CSS3 pseudoclass ['::first-letter'](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp) if you don't care about older browser versions!
.date

```css
.date{
      display:inline-block;
}
.date::first-letter {
  text-transform: lowercase;

}
```

```html
<span class="date">B.1234</span>
```

Comment: Browser support is hardly an issue, since this is supported since IE 5.5 (provided you use a single colon). A bigger problem is the fact that this doesn't work for inline and inline-block elements.

Comment: It works fine for inline-block elements, i made an update! @GolezTrol

Comment: It should be noted that the first letter in the span in the OP's code is actually a space, not the B ?

Comment: @adeneo Good point, but that doesn't seem to be a problem. It will also work with that space.

Comment: Yeah, first-letter doesn't match spaces, punctuation or other special characters, only letters, I'm just noting that the OP actually has a space for some strange reason in the span ?

Comment: I think the space is just a typo cause in the date tag there isn't one

Answer (score 1):

You could use the text-tranform property.

```
.dateGroup {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but in case there is so many caracters all the string will be in lowercase.